# how to get the first (or any single) value in GROUP BY without ARRAY_AGG?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions, vertica

I'm migrating some SQL from PostgreSQL 9.2 to Vertica 7.0, and I could use some help replacing postgres's cool [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-aggregate.html) feature with something that [Vertica](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SQLReferenceManual.htm?TocPath=SQL%20Reference%20Manual%7C_____0) (and possibly other RDBMS) supports, such as partitions and window functions. I'm new to these features, and I'd really appreciate your ideas.

The (working) query using array_agg ( **<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a92d5/3/0)</kbd>** ):

```
SELECT B.id, (array_agg(A.X))[1]
FROM B, AB, A
WHERE B.id = AB.B_id AND A.id = AB.A_id AND A.X IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY B.id;
```

If I try to naively select A.X by itself without the aggregation (i.e., to let the RDBMS pick - actually works with MySQL and SQLite), postgres complains. Running the same query but with "A.X" instead of "(array_agg(A.X))[1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-aggregate.html)":

```
ERROR:  column "a.x" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT B.id, A.X
```

I was thinking of trying a window function, e.g., something like from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686906/postgres-windows-function-with-aggregate-group-by/18692869):

```
SELECT email, FIRST_VALUE(email) OVER (PARTITION BY email)
FROM questions
GROUP BY email;
```

but I get the same error:

```
SELECT B.id, FIRST_VALUE(A.X) OVER (PARTITION BY A.id)
FROM B, AB, A
WHERE B.id = AB.B_id AND A.id = AB.A_id AND A.X IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY B.id;

ERROR:  column "a.x" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT B.id AS id, FIRST_VALUE(A.X) OVER (PARTITION BY A.id)...
```

Note that we don't care so much about getting the first value, we just need any (ideally deterministic) single value.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm somewhat at a loss as to what you're trying to achieve with `(array_agg(A.X))[1]`. Without an order by clause, this will give you the first of a randomly ordered list of A.X. The fact that you're getting the result is you're expected is sheer luck due to the fact that your stats make Postgres prefer a plan that fits…

Comment: I might be mistaken, but why don't you just use `SELECT B.id, min(A.X) from ... group by b.id`? I don't see why `array_agg()` would be necessary at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@a_horse_with_no_name's comment, along with that of Denis, was what we needed to rethink our approach. We have switched to MIN(). Thanks!